# POST data with curl & file_get_contents : Connection refused

Tags: php, api, curl, post, file-get-contents

im trying post data use curl & file_get_contents to 'url1' but get some error Connection Refused, but when post data to 'url2' its normal.

Curl :

```
$post = ['data1'=>'A','data2'=>'B'];
$ch = curl_init('url1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

curl: (7) Failed to connect to url1 port 82: Connection refused

file_get_contents:

```
$data = array('data1'=>'A','data2'=>'B');
$options = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query($data),
                    ),
            );
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents('url1', false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

Warning: file_get_contents(url1): failed to open stream: Connection refused

did i make mistake with this code ?

Comment: put `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch))` right before `curl_close`

Comment: you also forgot `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: also, port 82 is not default for websites (like 80), are you sure you must POST anything to 82?

Comment: @user1597430 i already use curl_getinfo & curlopt_post but still get same problem , the url target is use port 82

Comment: curl_getinfo is a debug function, you must check HTTP code and the server response to understand the problem

Comment: i got response like this
[url] =>url1 [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.999734 [namelookup_time] => 0.000179 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0

Comment: when i'm trying open the url in browser or post data with postman its normal, but when i put the url in my website script always connection refused

Comment: emulate all headers, which your browser send to the server

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to relate to target server or firewall configuration. You can check the target firewall settings or use all headers required at destination server. First try to use and add a proper value for origin header.

If the problem is not the firewall, you can take a look at https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS.